# A small riddle about two sisters

Tags: riddle

There is a stark difference between me and my younger sister.

Who am I?

**Edit (hint 1):** There are also some similarities. For example, both of us are not exactly pacific.

**Solution**

> I am the city of York. My younger sister is New York, we are not on the Pacific Ocean and the House of York is the basis for the House of Stark.

ps: This is my first attempt at a riddle. While it may be not new, I invented it by myself and wanted to share it.

Comment: This is not specific enough to state that any specific thing is THE answer.

Comment: Well I hope that when you will see the solution, you will see that there is a specific one

Comment: I think Bucky used that pun once during WW2

Comment: Poor old Bucky. But this specific riddle could not have been played with during WW2.

Comment: This seems pretty broad and those types of questions tend to get closed around here. Can you add some material that will narrow down the scope? We are not likely to have the same "a-ha!" moment that you did when creating the puzzle.

Comment: @EngineerToast each SE site has its own rules. This is my first post, maybe with enough downvotes I'll be motivated to understand it better :-) What I liked about the riddle was its tersity, rather than a long list of hints. But don't worry I understand that each one has its tastes.

Comment: I see it was voted to be put on hold. Are you interested in discovering the solution that I intended or you don't care for it?

Comment: @Francesco It would be best to have some closure, but if you can edit the question a bit perhaps the 'on hold' can be lifted. Otherwise it would be good to hear a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am going with

> You are Jon Snow and your little sister is Arya Stark

Because:

> there is a Stark difference between you two.

But this is probably wrong:

> The title talk about 2 sisters...

Comment: you are getting much closer :-) but still not there...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of guesses. (this question might be too broad)

- She is obviously younger that you, so I am going to say you are a person that had a younger sibling born in your teens.
- She is your little sister from Big Brothers, Big Sisters, so you are a Big Sister.
- You are from a mixed race step-family. <-- millions of people
- You are male, and that is quite a difference.
- And for those going down the GoT path, there are actually three different solutions that fit, all based on hair color alone...

  > Jon Snow and Sansa Stark, Robb Stark and Arya Stark, and Sansa Stark and Arya Stark

Comment: Hhhmmm this is not the right direction I fear.

Comment: that's what I was thinking about "stark difference." That it referred to color of some sort.

Comment: or Game of Thrones :D

Answer (score 0):

You are:

> either Frank or Billy Ocean

Explanation:

> "Pacific" hints at oceans. Your sister is Indian (also an ocean), whereas you are black, making a stark difference between the two of you.

Comment: This one makes a progress, but you're not there, yet